# MySQL - Left Join, Select all columns left, few columns on the right tables,

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to join two tables together as shown below, in the " * " section, I'm having trouble doing the following,

Operation: want to select all columns on the left, and just wanna attach few relevant columns from the right table to the left table. Instead of writing all the columns like left_table.column1, left_table.column2 ... so on is there another method which saves the manual coding?

```
SELECT * FROM nutrients LEFT JOIN measures ON nutrients.name=measures.name
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, add the table name before the `*` to select all columns of a table

```
SELECT nutrients.*, measures.colX
FROM nutrients 
LEFT JOIN measures ON nutrients.name=measures.name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select all column using `*` like following

```
SELECT nutrients.*,
       measures.name,
       measures.col2
FROM nutrients
LEFT JOIN measures ON nutrients.name=measures.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nutrients.*,
       measures.name,
       measures.column2,
       measures.column3
FROM nutrients
LEFT JOIN measures ON nutrients.name=measures.name
```

You can use this query which selects all from 1st table(left table) and specific columns from right table.

Hope this gives you what you need.